# What is the name for this distribution defined on a circle

Tags: distributions, density-function, terminology, circular-statistics

One can define the probability distribution:
$$
p(\theta; \alpha, \theta_0) = \frac{ e^{ \alpha \cos( \theta-\theta_0) }}{ 2 \pi I_0(\alpha)}
$$
over an angular variable $\theta \in [0,2 \pi]$.  By what name(s) is this distribution called?

($I_0$ is the modified Bessel function and serves to normalize the distribution)

Comment: Could you please define $I_0(\alpha)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [von Mises distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution), aka Tikhonov distribution, and plays the role similar to the normal distribution in 1D statistics.

For reference, $I_0(z)$ is the [modified Bessel function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) of order 0.